# Do I need to standardize both variables before simple regression analysis‘

Tags: regression, standardization

My hypothesis is that age predicts how resilient you are. So I need to run simple regression analysis on SPSS.
Age is measured in years and resilience is measured on a scale where you can achieve a total score between 1 and 94 (the higher the score the more resilient you are).
As I therefore have two different scales measuring the two variables, I feel I need to standardize the data for each variable. Is that correct? And would I need to do this for both variables? I don’t think I’ve seen age standardized before…

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to standardise anything. There is no need for your two variables to have the same scale. The only effect of standardising would be to make your regression equation harder to interpret.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Answered very directly and simply. Please continue to contribute to the site.